# SPS2013 List page add href to existing text using Jquery?

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, jquery, append-changes

Insert href link on existing text: abc, part of a DIV ID: wpfunc01 on a SPS2013 List page.
I guess this can be achieved via Jquery.

Please assist with the complete code to insert href on existing text: abc

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, here is it that may help others in the community -

In the below code, I have modified the TEXT Value: ALL with the same value and added Hyperlink.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Check the main container is ready
$('#WebPartWPQ2').ready(function(){
    // Get each div
    $('#scriptPagingWPQ2').each(function(){
        // Get the content
        var str = $(this).html();
        // Set the regex string
        var regex = /All/ig
        // Replace plain text links by hyperlinks
        var replaced_text = str.replace(regex, "<a href='http://www.example.com' target='_blank'>All</a>");
        // Echo link
        $(this).html(replaced_text);
    });
});


</script>
```

Comment: doesnt allows to mark answer for 2 days.